# Run CAR model (CARBayes package) with zip (a zero-inflated Poisson) family in R

Tags: r, model

I am trying to run the function "S.CARBym" using a zero-inflated Poisson (zip) family because my data *y* (cases of a disease) has too many zeros. I couldn't run it because the function asks to specify the `formula.omega` and I don't know which parameters/values I should use in this argument.

```
library(CARBayes)
library(rgdal)
library(spdep)

spat.data = readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "VAR_AMB") 

W=poly2nb(spat.data) 
W2 <- nb2mat(W, style="B")

eq1 = Cases~offset(log(Population))+temp+precip

modelbym1 <- S.CARbym(eq1, formula.omega=NULL, family="zip", data=spat.data, W=W2, burnin=100000, n.sample=300000, thin=20)

Error: a zip model was specified but the formula.omega argument was not specified
```

Answer (score 2):

The `formula.omega` argument is the formula for the logistic regression part of the model that decides if a response is zero or `Poisson(mu)`. These zeroes are "structural zeroes", and are different to any zeroes that might come from the Poisson distribution.

So the argument can be any one-sided formula in the columns of your data, similar to a logistic regression computed with `glm`, except that your response has already been specified on the left hand side of the `formula` argument, and is converted to a binary 0/1 value from 0/>1.

The simplest thing you can do is `formula.omega = ~1`, which (I think) will model them as completely at random. If you think structural zeroes are because of temperature (maybe this is tree growth data and you know trees don't grow at all if there's frost?) then `formula.omega = ~temp` might be sensible. This is the normal process of choosing covariates for a model - driven by knowledge of the subject area, the question you want to ask, and also by fit diagnostics. If adding a covariate doesn't sufficiently help the fit, you may as well drop it to make a simpler model.